# Update progress Causing Flash Effect in Partial Updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

i Showing a progress Bar as a Modal Pop Up.for this i

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginReq);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endReq);

        function beginReq(sender, args) {
            // shows the Popup 
            $find(ModalProgress).show();
        }

        function endReq(sender, args) {
            //  shows the Popup 
            $find(ModalProgress).hide();
        } 


    </script>
```

Update Panel trigger

```
<Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ChVerifed" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
 </Triggers>
```

This will execute for every asynchronous request. Can i put a condition for certain update panel make this to invoke .i not found a solution for this anywhere.In my project.there so many update panel and many are nested panel.this cause a flash effect everytime for an asynchrounus Request. i used the update parameter as conditional but this also not Working

Comment: can you give us the Trigger code for that Update Panel.

Comment: it cause's on a checkBox Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
 function beginReq(sender, args) {

   var updaterDiv = document.getElementById('<%=ChVerifed.ClientID%>');
    if (updaterDiv.checked) {
    $find(ModalProgress).show();
     }
  }
```

now only on if this check box is check then Your Pop Up Will Shows.